# Something weird happening with the casperjs/phantom js code (casper.exists() function)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Sample Code:

```
function myfunc(){
    ctxt = "this is the" + variable1 + "value";
    if (casper.exists(x('//p[@class="classname" and contains(text(), ctxt)]{
            //code1;
    }
}
```

When `myfunc` is called, the `if` block gets executed every time no matter whether `ctext` exists or not.
But if I hardcode the text instead of ctxt for example `"abcde"`, then it's execution doesn't occur.

This is what I mean:

```
contains(text(), "abcde")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a problem with the space around the position where `variable1` is inserted to. You could try to define `ctxt` like this:

```
ctxt = "this is the " + variable1 + " value";
```

The `exists` call should look like this:

```
casper.exists(x('//p[@class="classname" and contains(text(), "'+ctxt+'")]'))
```

You need to fix the closing brackets: `]{` should be `]'))){`.

The other thing is that you forgot to use the variable. Instead you just inserted the variable name (`ctxt`) into the XPath expression and not the variable value `"'+ctxt+'"`.

If this still does not work, you can try to normalize the white space of the text:

```
casper.exists(x('//p[@class="classname" and contains(normalize-space(text()), "'+ctxt+'")]'))
```

Comment: `contains()` function takes a string as argument and `ctxt` is a string. What is the difference between  `ctxt` and `"'+ctxt+'"`? As far as I can understand, it is executing `code1` every time because `ctxt` seems like a null string or something to it so it always exists. Please correct me if I am wrong. And sorry about the brackets. They were correct in the actual code. I reproduced them wrong in the question body.

Comment: Javascript is not like php, where you can insert variable values into strings: `$ctxt = "string"; $ns = "contains(text(), '$ctxt')"`. In javascript you need to concatenate (`+`) the string parts into a bigger string: `"contains(text(), "+ctxt+")"`. `ctxt` is not null if it was previously initialized. You did initialize it. If you didn't define it first with `var` it will be a global variable.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to javascript. Still learning. Now I understand why my code was not working. Thank you again.

Comment: "`ctxt` is not null if it was previously initialized.": That is not what I meant. I wanted to say that I was not properly inserting `ctxt` into the xpath expression so it was probably *seen* as null inside the xpath expression and so it matches the text on the screen every time.

Comment: You inserted nothing. The characters `ctxt` were already in the XPath expression string. It should have thrown an error since this is a wrong XPath expression. It should have been at least quoted `'... contains(text(), "ctxt")...'`. Otherwise the `contains` clause is not evaluated for the expression.